# Weird graphics after fresh arch install on virtual box

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, video

I just installed arch on virtualbox to test it out but for some reason it's not displaying correctly ( here's how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUjBS.jpg ) I'm using virtualbox version 4.2.16

Basically I just followed the beginner's guide and installed cinnamon after it was completed.

I also enabled 3d support, assigned 128mb to video memory and followed the steps here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Virtualbox#Arch_Linux_guests to install the guest additions. I think the problem is that the guest additions aren't working correctly since I tried to use the shared clipboard functionality and it didn't work either.

Comment: Seems like an improperly set screen resolution to me.

Comment: I have the same problem if I run full screen so it's probably something else